# Formatting regression results in R for latex

Tags: r, latex, regression

I am trying to create a regression results table in R for latex. I would like this table to have two separate columns: one for the estimates and one for the standard error. The following code

```
library(fixest)
library(car)
library(pander)

##Using the built-in CO2 data frame, run regression

i<- feols(conc ~ uptake + Treatment | Type, CO2, vcov = "hetero")
summary(i)

##Create regression table for latex

etable(i, postprocess.df = pandoc.table.return, style = "rmarkdown")

my_style = style.df(depvar.title = "", fixef.title = "",
                    fixef.suffix = " fixed effect", yesNo = "yes", default = TRUE)
setFixest_etable(style.df = my_style, postprocess.df = pandoc.table.return)

etable(i, style = "rmarkdown", caption = "New default values", se.below = NULL )

etable(i, tex = TRUE)

print(etable(i, tex = TRUE), file = "filename2.tex")
```

When put into Latex document on overleaf.com the following image is produced.
[image]

How can I alter my above code to have estimates and standard error in different columns in my table?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
modelsummary(your_regression, fmt=2, 
             estimate = c("{estimate}{stars} (std.error)"), 
             statistic = c(),
             output = "latex")
```

What I like with modelsummary too, is that it enable to put many different model as a list to compare them.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @léo-henry for suggesting `modelsummary`. I just wanted to point out that in the latest version of the package you can use the `shape` argument to display the estimates and standard errors (or other statitics) side-by-side. You will find details here: https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/articles/modelsummary.html#shape

Here is a minimal example:

```r
library(modelsummary)

mod <- lm(mpg ~ hp + drat, data = mtcars)

modelsummary(mod, shape = term ~ model + statistic)
```

[image]